# php file upload code doesn't work with iphones

Tags: php, iphone

I'm allowing users to upload pictures on a page on my php site. It works fine except with iphones, where every image is the same when they upload multiple images at the same time. I cant figure out what's wrong. Here is my upload code:

```
if(isset($_POST['uploaded']))
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $uploadOk = 1;

        //Get the temp file path and extension
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        //Check file size
        if (filesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i]) > 2097150)
        {
            echo "<font color=red>Sorry, your file is too large. </font>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        //Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "gif" 
            && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG" && $imageFileType != "PDF" && $imageFileType != "GIF") 
        {
            echo '<font color=red>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PDF, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</font>';
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != "" && $uploadOk == 1)
        {
            //Setup our new file path
            $newFilePath = "tempUpload/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) 
            {
                //remember the file name by adding it to fileNameArray and increment the number of designs
                array_push($fileNameArray, $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
                $numDesigns++;
            }
        }
        else
            echo "<font color=red> Your file was not uploaded<br></font>";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to find out why http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Plus, the default image name when uploading using a mobile is `image.jpg` and your code is probably failing because of a duplicate/existing filename in the array. Try using only one file if you're trying to upload more than one. If that works, you'll know why. I am next to 100% sure that is what's going on here.

Comment: if that's the case, then you will need to use a renaming function using a unique method.

Comment: Yes that must be why. is $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] == image.jpg? or is it $_FILES['upload']['name'] == image.jpg?

Comment: either way, the tmp file is the one used in the move function. You'll need to find yourself a renaming function that can handle multiple files. There are many out there.